# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ROOT at org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Hi I configured tomcat7 and its running fine outside eclipse but when I wrote a simple hello program using struts2 and tried to run on tomcat server it says

Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start....

with below mention statements in console in eclipse helios.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ROOT
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.<init>(StringManager.java:93)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(StringManager.java:225)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(StringManager.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.<clinit>(Catalina.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:238)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:425)
```

Comment: Can you tell me how did you deploy your code to tomcat?

Comment: What version of `java` does the tomcat try to run on when you start/deploy something to it from the eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly check you have a root folder in eclipse.
workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps

Should be a folder called ROOT

if its not there create it. Hope thats it ;)